# Django Leaflet disable zoom control

Tags: django, leaflet

I use Django 2.0 to draw maps and add [Control Zoom Bar](https://github.com/elrobis/L.Control.ZoomBar)
Everything work fine, but now I have 2 zoom control. According to the leaflet tutorial ( I use django-leaflet) I should disable default leaflet zoom control using `zoomControl: false` but somehow I cant find it where to configure it using Django-leaflet
I Tried

```
var map = new L.Map.djangoMap('map', { zoomControl:false });
```

but still it returns in an error, In Settings for LEAFLET_CONFIG there's only MAX_ZOOM and MIN_ZOOM. Any Idea how to do it? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I Achieved it by removing the zoomControl via removeControl using this code right before I called the zoom_bar control :

```
map.removeControl(map.zoomControl);
```